# UserDefault is not saving the value

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I have a survey form that appear only if the user still didn't answer survey every time the user launch the app. But even if I already answered the survey still its appearing. Here's how I'm doing it

```
//Get if questionaire is done
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let questionaire_done = defaults.string(forKey: "questionaire_done") {
    print(questionaire_done) // Some String Value
}else {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "questionaireSegue", sender: nil)
}

UserDefaults.standard.set("yes", forKey: "questionnaire_done") //set the questionnaire as done
```

Comment: Key name is different "questionaire_done" and "questionnaire_done" how it will work. Set and Get key both name are different please change that first and check.

Answer (score 1):

Store the value in before segue (navigation)

```
//Get if questionaire is done
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let questionaire_done = defaults.string(forKey: "questionnaire_done")  {
    print(questionaire_done) // Some String Value
}else {
    defaults.set("yes", forKey: "questionnaire_done") //set the questionnaire as done
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "questionaireSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

If you want to validate your condition then you like

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let questionaire_done = defaults.string(forKey: "questionnaire_done"), questionaire_done == "yes" {
    print(questionaire_done) // Some String Value
}else {
    defaults.set("yes", forKey: "questionnaire_done") //set the questionnaire as done
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "questionaireSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Key name is different  "questionaire_done" and "questionnaire_done" how it will work. Set and Get key both name are different please change that @Anbu.karthik also make same mistake for key.

Comment: @HardikThakkar - thanks for the info, i modified the answr

Comment: @user9900611 - your key name is different `questionnaire_done` from this `questionaire_done`

Answer (score 1):

```
if let questionaire_done = defaults.string(forKey: "questionaire_done")
```

has a different key to

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("yes", forKey: "questionnaire_done")
```

Spell the keys the same, or better still, use a constant string for the key.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the **key value** name should be always same but one more thing - you should write this after any "UserDefaults" operation - either **read** or **write**.

```
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Example -

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("yes", forKey: "questionnaire_done")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: You absolutely do not need to do this. It even says so in the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize. All that method does is wait.